# Drawing tangent vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

this is the solution provided from my class lecture notes. I have a question related to the graph drawing. Based on the calculation, we have two vectors, vector r(2) = <2,4> and vector r'(2) = <1,4>. According to the calculation of vectors, shouldn't those two vector have the same Y axis on the graph? Many thanks.
[image]

Comment: That would be true, if the tail of the pink vector was attached to the origin. You can see that it’s tail is moved to the tip of the green vector $(2,4)$ so the head of the green vector shifts to $(2+1,4+4)=(3,8)$. This is allowed, as the velocity vector is [free/non-localized](https://byjus.com/question-answer/what-are-localised-vectors/)

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, it is better to take one more example to appreciate the relevance of @Soham Saha'comment.

Let $M:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2, t\mapsto(\cos t, \sin t), v=M':t\to (-\sin t , \cos t)$

$$M(\frac{\pi}{4})=(\frac{\sqrt2}{2},\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}), v(\frac{\pi}{4})=(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2},\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}})$$

But because $v(\frac{\pi}{4})$ is the velocity vector to $M(\frac{\pi}{4})$, we prefer to represent it as the vector $$\overrightarrow {M(\frac{\pi}{4})N(\frac{\pi}{4})}$$with $N(\frac{\pi}{4})=(\frac{\sqrt2}{2}-\frac{\sqrt2}{2},\frac{\sqrt2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt2}{2})=(0,\sqrt2)$

[image]